# Django jwt token error. "Given token not valid for any token type, token_not_valid"

Tags: reactjs, django, axios

I am using Django Rest Framework for authentication and Axios in the frontend. When I pass the token to an axios.get method directly it fetches the API endpoint (getUserInfo) correctly, but when I use a variable (string) and pass it dynamically it fails and it gives the error described above.

First case: (succeeds)

```
const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer <token string>' },
  };

  await axios.get(URLS.FETCH_USER, config)
```

Second case: (fails)

```
const config = {
    headers: { Authorization:  `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
  };

  await axios.get(URLS.FETCH_USER, config).etc
```

Note that the token is fresh and taken directly from a postman login request.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` will add quotes to the token, just use the raw token: `Bearer ${accessToken}`

Comment: I actually tried that as well, still fails

Comment: How is `accessToken` defined and what does it look like?

Comment: Basically a nomal JWT token, I parse it from async storage, it returns the correct value - I test the val in postman -

Comment: Can you add the code where you store and retrieve the token to your question? Have you inspected the variable to make sure it is the correct string?

Comment: I fixed it, I guess async storage was returning a string inside "" (duplicate quotation marks) . For example, ""token"". I used JSON.parse and it solved the issue. Thanks for your time man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the token was a string inside extra two quotation marks "". That was the reason. I solved it by parsing the string as follows:

```
const config = {
    headers: { Authorization:  `Bearer ${JSON.parse(accessToken)}` },
  };
```